# What are the downsides to having resque jobs schedule themselves to run in the future?

Tags: resque

Are there any downsides to having resque jobs schedule themselves as opposed to one job spawning workers as it sees fit?

Here is an example

Approach 1:

```
class WorkerJob

  self.peform(model_id)
    do_heavy_stuff(model_id)
    Resque.enqueue_in(3.days, WorkerJob, model_id)
  end
end
```

or like this

Approach 2:

```
class WorkerJob1

   self.perform(model_id)
     do_heavy_stuff(model_id)
   end
end


class WorkerScheduler
   self.perform
     find_appropriate_ids_for_this_job.each |model_id|
       Resque.enqueue(Resque::WorkerJob1, model_id)
     end
   end
end
```

WorkerScheduler is scheduled to run every day. I see advantages so wanted to found out if there are any big downsides to approach 1.

I do see a big problem with making sure that redis is properly backed up and replicated, but wouldn't that be required regardless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complement that, you could use redis_failover: https://github.com/ryanlecompte/redis_failover

Comment: cool, thanks, will give it a go. just received ruby newsletter where redis_failover was featured :)